Azure workbook custom endpoint stopped working
We use an azure workbook with a custom endpoint query in it.
Suddenly the query stopped working with the following error:
We could not connect to the server, make sure CORS is enabled.
Tried everything, enable/disable cors, use different endpoint, .... always the same error message.
Any advise?


Could you please be less precise and vague? There is way too much info in your post to help you.

@Michal I added a screenshot. Don't know what more I can say about it...
